# @Retryable is not being triggered

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have tried to boil down the simplest retry scenario possible.  The retry is being ignored upon execution.

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//...
```

This is within a Service class:

```
public Boolean processItem() {
    Long id = 999L;
    try {
        retrieveItemWithRetry(id);
        return true;
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Retryable(include=NoResultException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500, maxDelay = 3000), maxAttempts = 5)
private void retrieveItemWithRetry(Long id) {
    retrieveItem(id);
}

private OrderRequest retrieveItem(Long id) {
    throw new NoResultException();
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Internal calls to `@Retryable` methods (within the same class) are not retryable; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855386/using-retryable-in-methods-define-in-spring-beans-base-class-are-not-retried/41856170#41856170) from yesterday, which explains why.

Further, `@Retryable` methods must be public.